# Variable name in R

Tags: r

I have a CSV file that I want to analyze in R. One of the variable names is `Team/NOC`. When I try to filter this variable I get an error message (probably because of the forward slash in the variable name).

- My code:

```
filter(Medals,Team/NOC=="Japan")
```

- The error message:

> Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
> i Input `..1` is `Team/NOC == "Japan"`.
> x object 'Team' not found

So, how can I solve this problem please?

Comment: Use backticks around the normally not-legal variable name: `filter(Medals, \`Team/NOC\` == "Japan")`